# I cannot get my honeycomb panel in Sumo Logic to display the correct colors

Tags: logic, panel, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have the following search:

_sourceCategory="/api/SQLWatch" AND "'checktype':'AGDetails'"
| parse "'synchronization_pair':'*'" as synchronization_pair
| parse "'Database_Name':'*'" as Database_Name
| parse "'synchronization_health_desc':'*'" as synchronization_health_desc
| parse "'AG_Name':'*'" as AG_Name
| parse "'DAG':'*'" as DAG
| IF (synchronization_health_desc = "HEALTHY", 1, 0) as isHealthy
| first(_messagetime) group by synchronization_pair,     Database_Name,     synchronization_health_desc, AG_Name, DAG, isHealthy

which produces results like this:

synchronization_pair    Database_Name   synchronization_health_desc AG_Name DAG Healthy
ServerA-ServerB         DB1             HEALTHY                     AG1     No  1
ServerC-ServerD         DB2             UNHEALTHY                   AG2     Yes 0

When I add a honeycomb panel to my dashboard with this search all the honeycombs are blue.

I add the following settings to my Visual Settings and they are still blue.

1   to  1   GREEN
0   to  0   RED

Please help.

Thanks.

Charles.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out!

the column in the first() is the value used for the visual settings

i changed the last line to the following and it works now!!!

| first(isHealthy) group by synchronization_pair,     Database_Name,     synchronization_health_desc, AG_Name, DAG //, isHealthy